# libevent multithreaded http server: can't reply evhttp_request successfully in sub threads

Tags: libevent

The problem is: client can't recv http response replied with "evhttp_send_reply" in sub thread in server side.

I've tried the model to setup multithreaded http server with libevent evhttp, below codes running in main thread:

```
    struct event_base *mpEventBase = event_base_new();
    struct evhttp *pHttp = evhttp_new(mpEventBase);
    evhttp_bind_socket(pHttp, "0.0.0.0", port);
    evhttp_set_gencb(pHttp, HttpGenericCallback, (void *)this);
    event_base_dispatch(mpEventBase);
```

then http server is setup and starts to accept connections from client.
But for general situation with processing the long-running code, I forward all the http request to sub thread and send http response in sub thread too.

```
    void HttpGenericCallback(struct evhttp_request *pRequest, void* arg) {
        Class *thiz = (Class *)arg;
        // run in sub thread in thread pool
        thiz->mpThreadPool->Run([thiz](struct evhttp_request *pReq){
            struct evbuffer* pEvbuf = evbuffer_new();
            if (!pEvbuf) {
                std::cout << "create evbuffer failed!\n";
                return ;
            }

            const char *pUrl = evhttp_request_get_uri(pRequest);
            evbuffer_add_printf(pEvbuf, "Server response. Your request url is %s", pUrl);
            evhttp_send_reply(pRequest, HTTP_OK, "OK", pEvbuf);
            evbuffer_free(pEvbuf);
        }, pRequest);
    }
```

BUT, I found after "evhttp_send_reply", the client DID NOT received any response. I'm not sure which step is wrong?
Beside, if I move the code running in sub thread to HttpGenericCallback, it will work!

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `HttpGenericCallback` is called and you are passing the `struct evhttp_request*` to your thread. The `HttpGenericCallback` finishes and probably destroys your `struct evhttp_request*`, while your thread keeps working with the already invalid pointer.

EDIT: I learned that the evhttp_request is not deleted until after evhttp_send_reply. Still, I would like to mention that the thread uses pRequest but should be using pReq, the Object that was passed to the function.